# Django server not working with AzureLogHandler (opencensus)

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, opencensus

I'm trying to connect my django project logs to Azure Application Insights using OpenCensus. The [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python-dependency#dependencies-with-django-integration) for montirong requests works well but I also want to send [telemetry logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#modify-telemetry-1) (not just requests) to Azure. Here is my django LOGGING configuration :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname).3s %(process)d %(name)s : %(message)s',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)-7s : %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'azure': {
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'class': 'opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler',
            'connection_string': 'InstrumentationKey=XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': os.environ.get('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'handlers': ['console', 'azure'],
        },
        'devdebug': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': os.environ.get('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        }
    },
}
```

Without `'azure'` handler in my root logger config, everything works fine. With `'azure'` handler, the server starts but doesn't work : I am unable to connect to it. I really don't know what is happening as it doesn't show me unusual logs (even with LOGLEVEL=DEBUG).
My handler configuration should be good as I can receive logs in Azure (when I run any manage command). Even when I run `manage runsslserver localhost:53215`, I receive logs but it is like my server is not running when I try to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

I have setup the logging via settings and have it working (although not using runsslserver. I have set the connection_string as an environment variable.

The problem I am having is that the 'django' logger does not work in production. All other loggers are sending messages but not that one??? I have a classic case of it works on my machine and our dev servers but not prod... FML!!

```py
INTEGRATIONS = ['postgresql', 'httplib','logging', 'threading']
config_integration.trace_integrations(INTEGRATIONS)

# Set the AppInsights Key as an env variable so it can be used by the logging system
os.environ['APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'] = 'InstrumentationKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

LOGGING = {
    'disable_existing_loggers': True, #False, #<-- if true then make sure that you have a 'django' and '' logger
    'filters': {
        "require_debug_false": {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
        'azure_verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s traceId=%(traceId)s spanId=%(spanId)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'azure':{
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter.AzureLogHandler',
            'formatter': 'azure_verbose'
        },
    }, 
    'loggers': {
        'mylogger': {
            "handlers": [
                "azure",
                "console",
                ],
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': [
                'azure',
                'console',
                ],
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': [
                'azure',
                'console',
                ],
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': [
                'azure',
                'console',
                ],
        },
    }, 
    'version': 1
}
```